# Why was it "The Sacrifice"?

Tags: plot-explanation, valhalla-rising

In [Valhalla Rising](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0862467/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_13), the final chapter (IIRC, Chap IV) is titled "The Sacrifice."

This is one of the few things I've not been able to figure out on my own, for sure. Why was the chapter called that? I don't believe One-Eye/Odin sacrificed himself for The Boy.

Although the Indians turn and leave The Boy at the end, this didn't really do The Boy any favors, alone, in a strange land, where he isn't even able to communicate with the natives, he's simply going to die of starvation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why did the Indians decide to end it this way?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19904/why-did-the-indians-decide-to-end-it-this-way)

Comment: Sure, I'm ok with this.

Comment: IMO, this is a different question. If I am not wrong, the prime reason for OP's post was to know why is this called "The Sacrifice"?

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher I guess the primary problem this comes down to is, if one ought to chose the "duplicate" based on the question or the answer. While I'd usually go for the former, SE's policy seems to prefer the latter. This *is* a different question, but it seems to be answered already by the answer to the other question.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: I do sense some overlap in the answer for both the questions, but wouldn't you like to have a more dedicated answer to this particular question?

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher Hmm, maybe. Especially since there *could* be more behind this title than what the other answer/question adresses. Maybe it would have been better to have the duplicate relationship the other way around or to ask a combined question in the first place, since they're unfortunately very related. But I tend to agree that this question might deserve to go on its own.